# Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize -- happens on server, but not on localhost

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I'm writing a suite of Protractor tests from the ground up for a new Angular webapp. My team has asked me to run my tests against their Test server instance. I've got my config file and a basic test spec set up, but as soon as I hit the main page and do a simple expect() statement, I get "Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds."

Here's my test:

```
describe('the home page', function() {
  it('should display the correct user name', function(){
    expect(element(by.binding('user.name')).getText()).toContain(browser.params.login.user);
  });
});
```

I cloned the dev team's git repo, set it up on my localhost, changed my baseUrl and ran my Protractor test against it locally. Passed without a hitch.

After some conversation with the dev team, I've determined that it's not a $http or $timeout issue. We use both of those services, but not repeatedly (I don't think they're "polling"). None of them should happen more than once, and all the timeouts are a half-second long.

What else could cause Protractor to time out like that? I wish it failed on my localhost so I could go tweak the code until I find out what's causing the problem, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the solution: check for console errors.

Turns out, one of our $http requests wasn't coming back because my Protractor tests were accessing the page via https, but one of our xhtml endpoints was at a non-secured location. This resulted in a very helpful console error which I had not yet seen, because it only occurred when accessing the site with WebDriver.

The error text: "The page at [url] was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I modified my baseUrl to access the site via regular http, and now everything is working fine.

Comment: glad you found a solution. could you add the console error to your question? maybe other users will search for it too.